# Customizing Layout for ListView (Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have been trying to give a "Cards UI" type layout to my ListView and came across [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/rtm60w). Using this implementation, I have tried to set up a ListView with the following code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_activity);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cardListView);
    final String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" }; // You have the necessary data to bind the list.

            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

However, I have been unable to give the ListView elements the background that is specified in the linked tutorial. They instead appear as follows (no cards background).

[image: No Background]

Could you please guide me on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Here's a better idea, use a Card-UI library - I liked this one: https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI

Comment: @svenoaks I did come across that but since this is my first android app, that was a bit over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the list_item.xml file as the layout to use for the items, try this:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Also, in the list_item.xml, add this line

```
android:id="@+android:id/text1"
```

In order for it to fill in the TextView.

Comment: hmm do you have a pic of what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks. I'm now trying to figure out how I can move the scrollbar to the right edge of the screen instead of its [current position](http://i.imgur.com/zgA9c3K.png).

Comment: Try changing ListView margin's to padding.

Comment: Could you possibly guide me on how to do that? I'm sorry, I'm very new to XML styling. :(

Comment: inside ListView tag change android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" to android:paddingLeft="16dp" same for right.

Comment: nm i see it doesn't work, you would have to set the margin on the list items themselves maybe